# How many group homomorphisms are there from $(\mathbb{Q}^+, \cdot\ )$ to $(\mathbb{Z}_m,+)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-homomorphism

How many group homomorphisms are there from $(\mathbb{Q}^+, \cdot\ )$ to $(\mathbb{Z}_m,+)$?

Of course, there is a trivial zero homomorphism. I think there are no more homomorphisms there but I am failing to prove it.

Comment: For any prime $p$ you can write each positive rational number $r\in\mathbb{Q}$ uniquely as $r=p^k\cdot\frac{s}{t}$ with $s, t\in\mathbb{N}$ coprime and also both coprime to $p$, and $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Define a map $\varphi:\mathbb{Q}^+\to\mathbb{Z}$ by setting $\varphi(r):=k$. Do you know if this function is a group homomorphism?

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* The fundamental theorem of arithmetic says that $(\mathbb{Q}^+, \cdot\ ) \cong \prod_p (\mathbb Z,+)$, the product being over the prime numbers. Therefore, the question reduces to finding all group homomorphisms from $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ to $(\mathbb{Z}_m,+)$, which is much easier.